# angularjs giving error during function

Tags: angularjs, mongoose

I am trying to implement angular with mongoose, and i have created a service using:

```
test.factory('loginService', function($http){
    return
    {
        login:function(user)
        {
           var $promise = $http.post('data/user.js', user);
            $promise.then(function(msg){
            if(msg.data == 'success') console.log('success login')
                else
            console.log('login failed');
            })
        }
    }
});
```

But when i try to run the code, it gives error as:

```
login:function(user)
                      ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:497:10)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:112:15)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try that :

```
test.factory('loginService', function($http){

    var loginService = {};

    loginService.login = function(user) {
           var $promise = $http.post('data/user.js', user);
            $promise.then(function(msg){
              if(msg.data == 'success') {
               console.log('success login')
              }
              else {
                console.log('login failed');
              };
            });
        };

    return loginService;
});
```

I believe that a problem of { } with your if {} else {};

Answer (score 0):

The `return` and `{` must be on the same line, or it just returns nothing from the function.

```
return {
```